# Highlight one specific country in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, geojson, folium

I have a map drawn by folium as follow:

```
m = folium.Map(location = [51.1657,10.4515], zoom_start=6, min_zoom = 5, max_zoom = 7)
```

[image]

How can I get rid of neighbor countries and just keep Germany?
Or alternatively neighbor countries become fade, blur,pale or something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you have a json file containing the geometry (coordinates) for the country of interest, you can add a [`GeoJson`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.GeoJson) layer:

```py
import folium
import json

with open('datasets/world-countries.json') as handle:
    country_geo = json.loads(handle.read())

for i in country_geo['features']:
    if i['properties']['name'] == 'Germany':
        country = i
        break

m = folium.Map(location = [51.1657,10.4515],
               zoom_start=6,
               min_zoom = 5,
               max_zoom = 7)


folium.GeoJson(country,
               name='germany').add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

and you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks... could you please elaborate on the "LayerControl"

Comment: You are just adding a layer (controlled by the small  box at the top right) which allows you to highlight the geometry specified in `folium.GeoJson()`.

Comment: I were searching google "Folium, how to get country with coordinates", This was the first answer that came up. But I want to do `place = [Lat, Lng]` `land = place.country`

Comment: Thank you, I applied the same approach and highlighted specific states